# Check for Multiple Type Casting in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I am trying to do multiple class casting to do some operation like UIBarButtonItem or UIControl.

is there a way to do both on the same line? Like:

```
if let x = sender as? UIControl, sender as? UIBarButtonItem {
print (x)
}
```

I have tried many ways but still not able to cast multiple class in one line.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `x`? I think that would matter for how specific you have to be when casting.

Comment: What type do you expect `x` to be here? If you wrote `if let x: SomeType = ...`, what would `SomeType` be? If you can't write down a type, neither can the compiler. And there must be exactly one type for every variable. So as Daniels asks, it all comes down to what you plan to do with x. If it's just `print`, then you mean `if sender is UIControl || sender is UIBarButtonItem`, but I'm betting you mean something other than `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **switch** for Type Casting:

```
switch sender {
case let x as UIControl:
    print(x)
case let x as UIBarButtonItem:
    print(x)
default:
    break
}
```

More info in Swift docs here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html

Comment: @topgun you haven’t given us you exact use case, but even though this more direct answer to what you were asking at face value, it’s actually not a good solution to the underlying problem you’re trying to solve. I have a very strong feeling you’re dealing with an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 6):

Swift is a statically typed language. All variables have a single type that's known at compile-time. Unlike dynamically typed languages (Python, Ruby, Smalltalk, Javascript, etc.), there's no way to directly do something like this:

```
let x: String or Int
if condition { x = 123 }
else { x = "string" }
```

Imagine if it were possible: what would be the value of `sqrt(x)` if `x` was a `String`? What would be the value of `x.uppercased()` if `x` was an `Int`?

Instead, such "OR types" are encoded as either enums (who explicitly enumerate all supported members as cases with associated values), or as protocols. Protocols have the added benefit that they explicitly state what behaviour is expected out of conforming types, and they're open ended to conformance by future types.

The most general protocol is `Any`, which captures ALL types. Its generality is both its strength and its weakness. While you can assign any value to it, you can do very little with it directly, because there are very few operations supported by *all* types.

In your case, it would be most fitting to make a protocol, add to it whatever functionality you want to access, and conform your desired types to it.

```
protocol Fooable {
     func foo()
}

extension UIControl: Fooable { 
     func foo() {
          print("I am a UIControl!")
     }
}

extension UIBarButtonItem: Fooable {
     func foo() {
          print("I am a UIBarButtonItem!")
     }
}

if let fooableThing = sender as? Fooable {
    fooableThing.foo()
}
```

Comment: what if its from UIBarButtonItem rather than UIView?

Comment: @kforkarim That's a completely different question.

Comment: What if you check if the object conforms to UIResponder? @kforkarim -- Or since UIBarItem directly conforms from NSObject, what if you check for NSObject, would it be too broad?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to explicitly indicate the UIControl/UIBarButtonItem inheritance from `Fooable`?

Comment: I think 'such "OR types" are expressed as protocols' is very misleading. OR types (sum types) in Swift are expressed as enums; AND types (product types) are expressed as structs and classes. Protocols describe types, they aren't themselves part of the algebra. Fooable isn't "UIControl OR UIBarButtonItem," it's "a type that is able to foo()," which may be multiple types, one type, or no types in this system.

Comment: @RobNapier Hmm, yeah I went against the common meaning of AND/OR types. `Fooable` isn't formally "UIControl OR UIBarButtonItem", but in this case, it is. Although somebody could retroactively conform other classes to `Fooable`, which could be an issue. How would you word this better?

Comment: We can instead talk about what a type CAN do. These CAN types are expressed as protocols. The broadest CAN type is "Any," which in fact, can do *nothing*. Every type can "do nothing," so every type meets the requirements of Any.  Or we can talk about one type OR another. Those are expressed as enums with associated data.